# Wordpress Plugin Activation Message

Tags: wordpress

I am making a simple plugin for Wordpress and I am having a little trouble trying to get a activation message displayed. I think my problem might be a simple syntax issue. The message is never displayed after activating the plugin what am I missing? The code executes past AnticsActivator::Activate() but nothing is displayed.

Here is a sample of what I have now:

```
function DisplayActivationMessage() {
    echo "<div class='notice notice-success is-dismissible'><p>Plugin was Activated...</p></div>";
}

function AnticsActivate() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/antics-activator.php';
    AnticsActivator::Activate();
    add_action('admin_notices', 'DisplayActivationMessage');
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'AnticsActivate' );
```

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing this carefully: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Process_Flow

Comment: can you post some code?